# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'srcObject')

Tags: reactjs

showing Error in Context.jsx

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import Peer from 'simple-peer';

const SocketContext = createContext();
const socket = io('https://localhost:5000');

const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [callAccepted, setCallAccepted] = useState(false);
    const [callEnded, setCallEnded] = useState(false);
    const [stream, setStream] = useState();
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [call, setCall] = useState({});
    const [me, setMe] = useState('');

    const myVideo = useRef(null);
    const userVideo = useRef(null);
    const connectionRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
            .then((currentStream) => {
                setStream(currentStream);
                console.log(`currentStream`, currentStream)
                console.log(` myVideo.current`,  myVideo.current)
                
                myVideo.current.srcObject = stream;
            });

        socket.on('me', (id) => setMe(id));

        socket.on('callUser', ({ from, name: callerName, signal }) => {
            setCall({ isReceivingCall: true, from, name: callerName, signal });
        });
    }, []);
    const answerCall = () => {
        setCallAccepted(true);
        const peer = new Peer({ initiator: false, trickle: false, stream });

        peer.on("signal", (data) => {
            socket.emit("answercall", { signal: data, to: call.from });
        });

        peer.on("stream", (currentStream) => {
            // here currentStream  is differen as like parameter
            // here i'm setting another user video 
            userVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
        })
        peer.signal(call.signal) // at call.signal setby setCall
        connectionRef.current = peer;

    }

    const callUser = (id) => {
        const peer = new Peer({ initiator: true, trickle: false, stream })
        peer.on("signal", (data) => {
            socket.emit("calluser", { userToCall: id, signalData: data, from: me, name });
        });

        peer.on("stream", (currentStream) => {
            // here currentStream  is differen as like parameter
            // here i'm setting another user video 
            userVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
        });

        socket.on('callaccepted', (signal) => {
            setCallAccepted(true);
            peer.signal(signal);
        })
        connectionRef.current = peer;

    }
    const leaveCall = () => {
        setCallEnded(true);
        connectionRef.current.destroy;
        window.location.reload();

    }
    return (
        <SocketContext.Provider value={{ call, callAccepted, myVideo, userVideo, stream, name, setName, callEnded, me, callUser, leaveCall, answerCall }}>
            {children}
        </SocketContext.Provider>
    )
}

export { ContextProvider, SocketContext };
```

At line number 27,
i'm making Video Chat application but useRef is not working from other component (VideoPlayer.jsx) why not setting up  Stream At Video Playe. in Video Player I've already use ref={myVideo}.

> > video playsInline muted ref={myVideo} src='' autoPlay className='video' />

- here is  videoPlayer.jsx

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { Grid, Typography, Paper } from '@mui/material';

import { SocketContext } from '../Context';


const VideoPlayer = () => {
//  const {datas} = useContext(SocketContext);
 console.log(SocketContext)
  const { name, callAccepted, myVideos, userVideo, callEnded, stream, call } = useContext(SocketContext);
  console.log(` Stream`,stream)
  return (
    <div>
      <Grid container className='gridContainer'>
        {stream && (
            <Paper className='paper'>
              <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                <Typography variant='h5' gutterBottom>{name || 'Name'}</Typography>
                <video playsInline muted ref={myVideo} src='' autoPlay className='video' />
              </Grid>
            </Paper>
            // My video Playes
          )}


        {callAccepted && !callEnded && (
            <Paper className='paper'>
              <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                <Typography variant='h5' gutterBottom>{call.name || 'UName'}</Typography>
                <video playsInline ref={userVideo} autoPlay className='video' />
              </Grid>
            </Paper>
            //  user video player
          )}

      </Grid>
    </div>
  )
}

export default VideoPlayer
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's about how you use that ref.
You should use the ForwardRef construction.
Look here - https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html.
VideoPlayer.jsx

```
import {forwardRef} from 'react';
function VideoPlayer (props, ref) {
 return (
   <video playsInline muted ref={ref} src='' autoPlay 
   className='video' />
 )
}
const refVideo = forwardRef(VideoPlayer);
export default refVideo;
```

Comment: i have added videoPlayer.jsx code please Check

Comment: const { name, callAccepted, myVideos, userVideo, callEnded, stream, call } = useContext(SocketContext);  
check for myVideoS - should be myVideo.  
But i think this does't solve the problem, check the forwardRef link, and wrap your component with it